# Multiple Datepicker fileds id

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a long html document with like a hundred of datepickers. Surely each has its own id in the form of (DueDate'num'), like "DueDate401":

```
<div id="DueDate">
  <label for="DueDate">Due date:<br></label>
  <input name="DueDate" type="date" id="DueDate401"/>
</div>
```

JS for processing event is as follows:

```
$(function() {
$( "#DueDate401" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat:"d-M-yy",
    showButtonPanel:true,
    changeMonth:true,
    changeYear:true
}); 
});
```

I have a vague idea that something like this should be used:

```
document.getElementById("DueDate"+id)
```

but not sure. Would appreciate assistance.

UPDATE: Oh yeh, the question)))) The above JS example shows how a reference is made to a SPECIFIC datepicker field. Since every next datepicker changes its id, I do not know how to change this Javascript to address all datepickers.

Comment: What is the question exactly? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use class as well. name the input's class names as DueDate,

then you can use like this

```
$(function() {
$( ".DueDate" ).datepicker({
dateFormat:"d-M-yy",
showButtonPanel:true,
changeMonth:true,
changeYear:true
}); 
});



<input name="DueDate" class="DueDate" type="date" id="DueDate401"/>
```

Comment: Oops, how do I define class ... Not a very pro at JS, sorry.